# MS SQL linked server - Deferred prepare could not be completed

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I'm having an issue with querying from linked server using OPENQUERY in MS SQL. There has been some topics and solutions already presented for this issue, but noone of the fixed this one.

Now, I'm trying to run following procedure, which was made to copy all new data from one database to another:

```
USE_GS_DB

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @tsql varchar(8000);
DECLARE @idexternal varchar(255);
DECLARE @timeexternal datetime;

SET @idexternal = (SELECT external_id FROM dbo.insert_data WHERE test_type = 1);
SET @timeexternal = (SELECT external_time FROM dbo.insert_data WHERE test_type = 1);

SELECT @tsql = '
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(TESTSERVER, ''
SELECT [open_test_uuid]
      ,[time_utc]
      ,[client_version]
FROM [GS_DB].[dbo].[table_data] WHERE [time_utc] >= ''' + convert(varchar, @timeexternal, 121) + ''' and [open_test_uuid] <> ' +  cast(@idexternal as varchar) + ''') ';

EXEC('INSERT INTO [GS_DB].[dbo].[c_table_data]
      ([open_test_uuid]
      ,[time_utc]
      ,[client_version])' + @tsql)
```

`@idexternal` and `@timeexternal` are set in another table that are overwritten with last input every time when copy occurs (set up by trigger).

I've tried to run only first part of procedure (one with `OPENQUERY`) without WHERE condition and everything works as intended, but as soon as I add condition, I get following message (doesn't matter if I use variables or I just input the parameter):

> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "TESTSERVER" returned
>   message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.". Msg 8180, Level
>   16, State 1, Line 1 Statement(s) could not be prepared. Msg 102, Level
>   15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '1'.

I have similar procedure for another database and it work without any issues. Would anyone have any solution or comment to this issue?

Comment: Just a general question. Why Dynamic SQL?

Comment: Hello Evaldas! Reason is that I want to run this procedure every 5 minutes to input new data from external DB and I want it to be automated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the syntax of the `WHERE` clause that you are constructing:

`...WHERE [time_utc] >= ' +  cast(@timeexternal as varchar) + 'and...`

This is building a SQL string like `...WHERE [time_utc] >= Jun 22 2015  3:56PMand...` which then can't be prepared, as it is not valid SQL.
Try something like the following:

`select '...WHERE [time_utc] >= ''' +  convert(varchar, @timeexternal, 121) + ''' and...'`

Comment: I'd also suggest that if this is something that you will be executing a lot, it's an ideal candidate for putting into a stored procedure on the target server, then it doesn't have to be compiled each time (although this *may* not happen due to parameter sniffing), and you can also reduce the traffic between servers because you only need to call the SP with the appropriate parameters (`@timeexternal` and `@idexternal`)

Comment: Hello Ed! Convert really fixed an issue with inability to prepare statement, really appreciated your help. I run into syntax error now at place of time_utc, **Incorrect syntax near 2014** (convert returns me 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000); checked syntax multiple times and string should now be set up exactly the way it is needed (based on what convert function returns me).

Comment: Also updated code in main question how it is now; I used cast instead covert on idexternal string, since it has no connection with date.